# How to change struct parent variables from declaration?

Tags: c++

```
struct Movement {
  int left = 0;
  int right = 0;
};

struct TurnLeft : Movement {
  left = 200; 
  right = MAX_SPEED;
};
```

I want TurnLeft to override left and right. How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way of doing this without a *constructor*. Example:

```
struct Movement {
  int left = 0;
  int right = 0;
};

struct TurnLeft : Movement {
  TurnLeft() : Movement{200, MAX_SPEED} { }
};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BXqirUtHQNwNGKsU)